# How to format HTML datepicker by using js

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I want to format the date value I got from the HTML `datepicker`. I used the js class `new Date()`, and put the date value got from the HTML `datepicker` in it. The result shows that the actual date after the formatting is one day smaller than the date I selected in the `datepicker`, can anyone help me solve this issue? The code is as follow.

```
 $("#date").on("click",function(){
    var date2 = new Date($("#date").val());
    alert(date2.getDate());
```

Here is the declaration for HTML part

```
<input type="date" name="date" id="date" max="2013-12-31" min="2013-01-01">
```

Result

[image]

Comment: "the HTML datepicker" ... huh?

Comment: @Pointy sry my mistake, I changed already

Comment: I can't duplicate the your problem http://jsbin.com/nocuzewoho/edit?html,js,output  can you provide more info

Comment: @K Scandrett You actually did. I've updated the question, you can see the screenshot I added

Comment: The plugin will provide methods to do this. It would be better if you can use the plugin methods itself.

Comment: What plugin method, can you tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `getUTCDate()` instead of `getDate()` to ignore UTC offsets.

In your case you're GMT-5, so it is removing 5 hours from the date entered and that puts it into the previous day when using getDate().

`toUTCString()` will return the full date.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getUTCDate

Example: http://jsbin.com/vojanisiqu/1/edit?html,js,output